# Jenkins Prometheus plugin not generating any data

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus

I have Jenkins running at `https://jenkins.example.com:8443`. We installed the Prometheus plugin and restarted the instance with no issues.

When browsing to `https://jenkins.example.com:8443/prometheus/` I get a 200 but no data is generated. Left the page open and no data generated more than an hour later, restarted the instance, still just a blank page. I have installed the Prometheus plugin on a bunch of other instances with the same exact setup and configuration and those have no issues. Running Jenkins ver. 2.164.1 with Prometheus 2.0.6. I tried setting up logging for the plugin but not seeing any logs being generated either. The Prometheus config has the Jenkins instance configured in the scrape and Jenkins target is up in the targets page of the Prometheus UI. But again, no data is being generated.

Plugin documentation is here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/prometheus/

Comment: I too facing the same issue. Prometheus endpoint showing blank on my browser. So did you solve this issue?

Comment: @user4948798 Is this issue resolved? I am facing similar issue!

Comment: @AkshayBadri, Yes. It was a Jenkins Prometheus plugin issue. After upgrading it to 2.0.9 issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate Access Keys in the metrics section and access the url **https://jenkins_ipaddres:portnumber/metrics/accesskey** you would now be able to view the metrics.

Path to generate the Access Keys:

Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Systems > Metrics >> Add >> Generate >> Save

Thanks